# COUNTIF function not counting cells with specific text values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Even for a simple function `=COUNTIF(A2:A12,"Production Control")` the function will not count the cells that say Production Control in them.  Anything that I am missing?

Comment: Leading/Trailing spaces? Or other non-printable characters?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding wildcards (`*`) around your qualifier

As they say, a picture is worth a thousand words!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also Check for the associated blanks and spaces as sometimes that is also been affected in excel formulas.
It would return nothing even though it is having the fields you looking for.